# Must you show your cards if you are playing the board?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I was curious, if you do like a monster bluff in hold em' and your hand is literally the board, someone calls you and its time to show your cards.  Do you legally have to show your cards in this case, or can you simply say, my hand is the board and muck your cards?

Comment: This answer is going to be *highly* dependent on the room and floor personnel. I have successfully made the claim that my hand is the board after mucking my cards and a player challenged it; my five cards are "face up". But I can see how another person would have ruled another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes, always. Most poker rooms and rule books state plainly that you must table your cards face up to have any claim to a pot. Tabling your cards means placing them face up on the table, so that all players can see them. If you say my hand is the board and muck your cards your hand is dead and you will have no claim on the pot.

related posts:

[Do I have to show my hand in an "All-In" situation?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/do-i-have-to-show-my-hand-in-an-all-in-situation/2709#2709)

[In Omaha, Is it allowed to only show two holecards at showdown when claiming the pot?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/566/in-omaha-is-it-allowed-to-only-show-two-holecards-at-showdown-when-claiming-the)

[Can a bettor concede his hand without showing it?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-a-bettor-concede-his-hand-without-showing-it/742#742)

[Heads-up river, first to show mucks. Does second player have to show to win pot?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/heads-up-river-first-to-show-mucks-does-second-player-have-to-show-to-win-pot/4255#4255)

Comment: Interesting in that third link `A player may opt to throw his hand away after all the betting for the deal is over, rather than compete to win the pot. However, the other players do not lose the right to request the hand be shown if he does so.`  So it seems even if you do attempt to muck other players have the right to see your hand in this situation?

Comment: @KDiTraglia Yes they do, and in a split pot like this, it can sometimes cost them half the pot to see that hand, some houses will say that hand is live and gets half the pot.

Comment: This answer is going to be *highly* dependent on the room and floor personnel. I have successfully made the claim that my hand is the board after mucking my cards and a player challenged it; my five cards are "face up". But I can see how another person would have ruled another way.

Comment: @JimBeam I have ruled it both ways. Its one of those best interest of fairness things. As a player though I would never take the risk of the downside by mucking a hand like that. Just not worth it.

Comment: Only in British casinos have I ever seen a player allowed to play the board after discarding his hand. No American casino would allow such a thing--discarding your hand surrenders your share of the pot, even if your opponent is only playing the board (and he'll have to show two valid cards to do so).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Is That common in British Casinos? Is it the rule?

Comment: As far as I know. I only claim expertise in the American game and have heard about others.