# Poker Hi Low 8 or Better - calling your hand

Tags: omaha-hi-lo, showdown

After the final bet, 4 players call, and we show in turn. The first player calls low hand and shows all his cards. The second player calls his low hand (loses) but shows only 2 of the 4 cards. The other 2 players show all their cards for high hand. Then the second player puts down the other 2 cards to show high and wins. Is that right?  Are the 2 cards the second player held back dead because he did not show all cards when it was his turn?

Second question, since we are playing Hi-Low, can any of the players (who called) ask to see the second player other cards (or cards) after the winners were determined?

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. The second one has been asked before. https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/566/3816

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two different ways to play high-low split poker: "declare" and "cards speak". With the "declare" option there's also "in-turn" and "simultaneous" (simultaneous declarations are done by players arranging chips in their hand under the table and exposing them at the same time). The exact rules should be determined before the game starts.

Generally in "declare" games, a player who declares low cannot win high (and vice versa), so player two in your game is out of luck. Also, a player who declares "swing" must win both high and low to get anything (i.e., he cannot win only high if his low is beaten).

Casinos rarely, if ever, play "declare" games. "Cards speak" is easier and leads to fewer arguments. Under these rules, all players simply show their hands and the best low and best high split the pot. To increase the chance for players to scoop a whole pot, "cards speak" games are generally played with a qualifier for low: that is, a player cannot win low unless his hand is, say, 8-high or below.

High-low declare games are NOT played with a qualifier, so if a game is announced as "Stud-8" or "Omaha-9", that implies cards speak with the given qualifier for low.

In all poker games, if the hand reaches showdown, any remaining player may ask to see any hand, but it is generally both a good idea and good etiquette to allow players to fold without showing.